# Select all tuples of a Table, with a dummy column showing which tuples satisfy a condition

Tags: sql

If I add a where condition in query it gives me filtered results. But what i need is a result in which all the rows (filtered + unfiltered) are shown with an additional (dummy) column which tells me by some means(say a boolean value) that a specific row met the "where condition" .

Comment: Oracle 11g in RHEL 6.2...

Comment: if you can give us your `filtered` condition then it will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Taking the example `where` condition:

```
where col1 = 2
```

Use a `case` to add an additional column indicating if the condition is met:

```
select *, case when col1 = 2 
               then 'true'
               else 'false'
          end as `dummy`
from your_table
```